# UICollectionView Invalid number of items, arrays adding and deleting elements

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, ios6, uicollectionview

I am working on an iPhone app with a UICollectionView, and am trying to create folders like the iPhones spring board. I have it working but am running into this error regarding the addition and subtraction of cells using core data. I was hoping someone could explain how I avoid this error? Thank You in advance.

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of items in section 0.  The number of items contained in an existing section after the update (4) must be equal to the number of items contained in that section before the update (3), plus or minus the number of items inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of items moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

------mainViewController

```
            //**Document One**
            //get first doc and create it as a sub doc
            Document * docToCopy = [[self birds] objectAtIndex:longPressFolderLayout.pinchedCellPath.row];
            SubDocument *doc = [[SubDocument alloc] initInsertingIntoManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
            [doc setTitle:docToCopy.title];
            [doc setThumbnail:docToCopy.thumbnail];
            [doc setIsFolder:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]];
            [doc setDate:docToCopy.date];


            //**Document Two**
            //get second doc and create it as a sub doc
            Document * docToCopy2 = [[self birds] objectAtIndex:cellAttributes.indexPath.row];
            SubDocument *doc2 = [[SubDocument alloc] initInsertingIntoManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
            [doc2 setTitle:docToCopy2.title];
            [doc setThumbnail:docToCopy2.thumbnail];
            [doc2 setIsFolder:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]];
            [doc2 setDate:docToCopy2.date];
            [self add:@"folder" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"folderDefaultImage"] date:[NSDate date] folder:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]];

            //**Folder**
            //create a folder and append both sub docs and then remove the original docs
            Document * origFolder = [[self birds] objectAtIndex:([[self birds]count]-1)];
            [origFolder appendDoc:doc];
            [origFolder appendDoc:doc2];
            [origFolder setIsFolder:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]];
            currentOpenFolder = origFolder;
            [self removePageAtIndex:longPressFolderLayout.pinchedCellPath.row];
            [self removePageAtIndex:cellAttributes.indexPath.row];
```

------DocumentNSManagedObject

```
- (void)appendDoc:(SubDocument *)doc
{
[[self mutableSetValueForKey:@"subDocument"] addObject:doc];
[(NSMutableArray *)[self subDocumentsOrdered] addObject:doc];

    NSError *error = nil;
[[self managedObjectContext] save:&error];
}
- (void)deleteDoc:(SubDocument *)doc
{
    [[self mutableSetValueForKey:@"subDocument"] removeObject:doc];
    [(NSMutableArray *)[self subDocumentsOrdered]removeObject:doc];
    NSError *error = nil;
[[self managedObjectContext] save:&error];
}
- (NSArray *)subDocumentsOrdered
{
if (!subDocumentsOrdered)
{
subDocumentsOrdered = [[[[self subDocument] allObjects] sortedArrayWithOptions:NSSortStable|NSSortConcurrent usingComparator:(NSComparator) ^(SubDocument *stroke1, SubDocument *stroke2)
                          {
                              return [[stroke1 date] compare:[stroke2 date]];
                          }
                          ] mutableCopy];
}
    return subDocumentsOrdered;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a very similar problem recently in my app. If you look at where you are adding your pages I bet you are not saving them to the NSManagedObjectContext. A simple solution is just by writing:

```
[[self managedObjectContext]save:nil];
```

Hope this helps. Good luck.

Comment: Do you know what was causing the problem and why this was the solution?  If so it would improve this question / answer to add some detail here.

Comment: For instance the save shown here may simply trigger a complete rebuild of the view which, whilst it makes the error go away, may not yield the best performance, which could become a problem as your app develops or when you test on a device.

Answer (score 4):

The error message is to do with the `UICollectionView` and the information you are providing it with as you add and remove items or respond to it's `UICollectionViewDataSource` methods such as `collectionView:numberOfItemsInSection:`

Basically the actions you are performing on the `UICollectionView` don't add up.

It's telling you that in Section 0

- You start with 3 items in the section, i.e. you responded to `collectionView:numberOfItemsInSection:` by returning `3`.
- You didn't insert or remove any items.
- You now say there are 4 items in the section, i.e. you responded to `collectionView:numberOfItemsInSection:` by returning `4`.

So the `UICollectionView` is complaining that you telling it there is an extra item in the section but you didn't tell it where to insert it.  So this is what you need to do.

It doesn't really have much to do with `core-data` it's to do with the `UICollectionView`

Comment: I sort of already knew this just looking at this problem when it comes to table views. Are their any specific tips in my code you can provide. Thank You.

Comment: The code you supplied doesn't directly relate to the error message shown, so no tips there.  You just need to make sure you are feeding the UICollectionView the correct information as you change your data model. There is no "automatic" relationship between a core-data model and a UICollectionView, it's up to you to make sure that you operate on both sides consistently.  i.e. if you remove an item from the data model, make sure you remove it from the view, add an item to the model add it to the view etc.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you are saying. I am adding and deleting the items there. what do I have to call to the collection view to update and how frequently do I have to call it? Every time I add one?

Comment: You would call the methods like 'insertItemsAtIndexPaths:' and 'deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:'.  You would do this when ever you perform the corresponding actions on the data model.   So if you are saying that the code above is where you add and remove things from your data model then this is where you would add and remove them from the view also.  I'm not sure how good the sample code for UICollectionView is, but you could look at sample code for a UITableView to understand how you interact with this type of view to keep them in sync with the data model as it changes.